# Using ajv to guarantee the value types, at specific indices, in an array

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

I am trying to use ajv to guarantee an array adheres to strict rules about what is a valid value. I'm not sure about what modifications or additional keywords to use to achieve the result I'm looking for.  Could use some insight.

Note: I have this working another way, without using JSONSchema validation. I was just curious if JSONSchema validation could be used to accomplish the same goal.

The rules are:

1. It can contain any number of items, we only care about indices 0 and 1.
2. The first item, index 0, must be a string.
3. The second item, index 1, must be an object.
4. If the item at index 0 or 1, regardless of the length of the array, is valid for either index, insert a default value for the other item at the appropriate index.
5. If the array has no items, insert both default values at the appropriate index.

Here is a code snippet that hopefully explains what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks.

```
const schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "default": {}
        }
    ]
};

function fn( array ) {

    ajv.validate( schema, array );
    console.log( array );

}

fn([]);
fn([ '1' ]);
fn([ { bar: 2} ]);
fn([ 'word', { foo: 3 } ]);
fn([ 'word', 42 ]);
fn([ [ 1, 2, 3 ],  { baz: 4 } ]);
fn([ 'word', { a: 1, b: 2 }, 42 ]);

// Actual results:

// [ '', {} ] => Expected
// [ '1', {} ] => Expected
// [ { bar: 2 }, {} ] => Not what I want
// [ 'word', { foo: 3 } ] => Expected
// [ 'word', 42 ] => Not what I want
// [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], { baz: 4 } ] => Not what I want
// [ 'word', { a: 1, b: 2 }, 42 ] => Expected, indices 0 and 1 are all I care about

// Desired results:

// [ '', {} ]
// [ '1', {} ]
// [ '1', { bar: 2 } ]
// [ 'word', { foo: 3 } ]
// [ 'word', {} ]
// [ '', { baz: 4 } ]
// [ 'word', { a: 1, b: 2 }, 42 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON Schema only does validation. It doesn't modify the value being validated. Since your example requires values to be inserted in special cases, JSON Schema can't do it.

But, you might ask, what about `default`? `default` is actually a meta-data keyword like `title` or `description`. It doesn't affect validation in any way. Many library authors have included support of some kind for this, but whatever they do, it is not standard behavior.

Comment: Thank you.  That clarifies things.  I use basic JSONSchema validation for a lot of things, but I am always puzzled at even just the validation piece. Doesn't, or shouldn't, the above schema example imply, through the use of the 'type' keyword, that values of that type are expected? For example, I would still expect, in the 7 example calls I gave, that 3 of them would fail validation since index 0 isn't a string and/or index 1 isn't an object.

Comment: AJV's, and other schema validator, documentation seems to imply that not only will other types pass the validation, but that this is normal and, somehow, makes logical sense.  Actually, it doesn't to me.  What's the point of validating against a type, if other types can pass your validation? I probably just need to grab some coffee and try to read the entire JSONSchema spec in hopes of some enlightenment. LOL. Anyway, thanks for the response. :)

Comment: I think that's a larger conversation than can be had in comments. Yes, it makes sense, and yes it's a different paradigm that requires you to think differently about the problem than you might be used to. If you add `"minItems": 2` to your schema, you should see more expected behavior.